# Sum rows with multiple ID

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT SUM(voc=1) AS s, SUM(voc=2) AS d, SUM(voc=3) AS p FROM `pl`;
```

But now I need to modify this query, so it'll `SUM` when `voc` is equal to the multiple numbers:

```
SELECT SUM ( voc = 1 OR voc = 7 OR voc = 3 ) as `s` FROM `pl`;
```

Unfortunately , the above is not working properly, I've read that this can be done using `CASE`, but my knowledge about that is too small...

Comment: Have you tried moving your condition to the where clause? I.e. where voc in (1,7,3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM ( CASE WHEN voc = 1 OR voc = 7 OR voc = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `s` FROM `pl`;
```

**UPD** As stated by @Raul in comment - `WHERE` should be much more effective, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `s` FROM `p1` WHERE voc IN (1,3,7);
```

**UPD2** Changed Sum's to Count's - thanks to @newtower

Comment: `SUM(voc) where voc=3` is not the same as `SUM(voc=3)`. In both cases `COUNT` would be better.

Comment: I need to get data count on how many fields with `voc=xx` exist in the table. Your queries don't help me since I need to select multiple voc, see the example: `SELECT SUM(OR)COUNT(voc = 1 OR 7 OR 3) AS 's', SUM(OR)COUNT(voc = 2 OR 8 OR 4) from pl;` (OR) means SUM or COUNT because I don't know which one will do this job.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Have you seen my comment?

Comment: @Cyclone: If you need to select on multiple voc then you may use my first query by slightly modifying it: `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN voc = 1 OR voc = 7 OR voc = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 's', SUM(CASE WHEN voc = 2 OR voc = 8 OR voc = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from pl;`

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Thank you Sergey, now I got it :)